# Run shiny app with admin user on non-admin login

Tags: r, shiny

I have two accounts at work. One user1 with internet connection without admin rights (the user i usally work with). And one user2 with admin rights but without internet connection.

To run R sufficiently fast with user1 i have to run R ("run program with another  user") and select user2 for that. So far so good.

If i want to run a shiny app, it will run at 127.0.0.1:PORT. However, that is not accessible from user1.

It makes perfect sense. However, i would like to ask if there is a possibility to see the app with user1 without have too much additional Setup. (I want to constantly develop the shiny app and not spending 10+ sec each time to get Access to the app,....)

Comment: This is all a bit confusing, but can't you `ssh` in, forwarding ports, so that `user1` can access ports on `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works:

Try running ipconfig from cmd to get your IP.

Then run:

```
runApp("C:/shinyapp", host="0.0.0.0", port=4040)
```

*(assuming that your app has a ui.R and a server.R)

Now let's assume that your IP was 190.159.180.16

Share your app using the following link:

http://190.159.180.16:4040

Answer (score 0):

One dirty fix, that just came to my mind is to also run the browser of choice with the user2 as well. It seems to work.

Maybe it helps somebody else as well.